# Where is this code dereferencing an invalid iterator? (C++)

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I have a loop

```
for(aI = antiviral_data.begin(); aI != antiviral_data.end();)
{
    for(vI = viral_data.begin(); vI != viral_data.end();)
    {
        if((*aI)->x == (*vI)->x && (*aI)->y == (*vI)->y)
        {
            vI = viral_data.erase(vI);
            aI = antiviral_data.erase(aI);
        }
        else
        {
            vI++;
            aI++;
        }
    }
}
```

But when ever antiviral_data contains an item, I get an error "vector iterator not dereferencable."  Why am I geting this error and where am I dereferencing an invalid iterator?

NB: So far th error only occurs when the if() statement is false.  I don't know what happens if the if() statement is true.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What are the sizes of the vectors?

If viral_data has more elements then antiviral_data, then, since you increment aI and vI at the same rate, aI would go out of bounds before the vI loop would end.

Take a short example here:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5;)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < 10;)
    {
        i++;
        j++;
    }
}
```

If you go over the for loops, you'll notice that the inner loop will not end until both j **and** i are 10, but according to your outer loop, i should *not* be more then 5.

You'll want to increment i (or in your case, aI) in the outer loop like so:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5;)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < 10;)
    {
        j++;
    }
    i++;
}
```

Comment: vI is always two, aI starts out at 0.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The dereferencing is happening at

```
((*aI)->x == (*vI)->x && (*aI)->y == (*vI)->y)
```

and it occurs when that statement is true for the last element in the `antiviral_data` list. In that case on the next iteration of the inner for loop you will be dereferencing `antiviral_data.end()` which is not allowed.